# Resizing armor/clothing to variant body types

Tags: modeling, scripting

I have several human body types which all share the same vertcount/order.  I'm looking to quickly resize armor and clothing I've made for the middle size to fit the other size variants.  I'm trying to use blender to accomplish this and fighting the urge to jump back over to max and do this.  In max this is an easy skin wrap / morpher combo process - very easy.  Is there anything here in blender similar? or any script that achieves this?